# Bash script to move files in directories listed in a textfile

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, zsh

I have a directory structure like this.

```
.
├── Round_1_Div2
│   ├── file1.txt
│   └── file2.txt
├── Round1Div2
│   ├── file3.txt
│   └── file4.txt
├── Round_2_Div2
│   ├── file1.txt
│   └── file2.txt
└── Round2Div2
    ├── file3.txt
    └── file4.txt
```

I need to move all files from **Round1Div2** to **Round_1_Div2** and **Round2Div2** to **Round_2_Div2**

Based on my little knowledge i made

```
  find *ound[0-9]Di* > rename.txt
  sed  -e 's/ound/ound_/;s/Di/_Di/' < rename.txt > newname.txt
```

*rename.txt* and *nename.txt* are created after running the above command

**rename.txt**

```
Round1Div2
Round2Div2
```

**newname.txt**

```
Round_1_Div2
Round_2_Div2
```

How can I move all files from the directory specified in each like to of *rename.txt* to the corresponding directory in *newname.txt*??
Thankyou.

Comment: is there any reason why you don't just rename the directories instead of moving the files?  i.e. `mv Round1Div2 Round_1_Div2` and `mv Round2Div2 Round_2_Div2`.  or, with perl rename, `rename 's/Round(\d)Div(\d)/Round_$1_Div$2/' */`

Comment: I can't rename *Round1Div2* to *Round_1_Div2* because Round_1_Div2 already exists and has different files in it. I could do it manually but I have a lot of them(the directory structure I have shown is just an example) Thank you for responding

Comment: How do you want to deal with name collisions?

Comment: It works perfectly with perl-rename(no need of *find*, because when we try to rename directories with *perl-rename* it copies files to the directory with the new directory name if a directory with the new directory name already exists, then, we can remove the old directory ). Thank you for responding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the perl `rename` utility (also known as `prename` and `file-rename`):

```
$ rename -n 's/Round(\d)Div(\d)/Round_$1_Div$2/' */*
rename(Round1Div2/file3.txt, Round_1_Div2/file3.txt)
rename(Round1Div2/file4.txt, Round_1_Div2/file4.txt)
rename(Round2Div2/file3.txt, Round_2_Div2/file3.txt)
rename(Round2Div2/file4.txt, Round_2_Div2/file4.txt)
```

The `-n` option makes this a dry-run, so that it only shows what it *would* do rather than actually doing it.  When you're sure it's going to do what you want, either remove the `-n` (which just renames the files, without any progress display or other output) or replace it with `-v` for verbose output:

```
$ rename -v 's/Round(\d)Div(\d)/Round_$1_Div$2/' */*
Round1Div2/file3.txt renamed as Round_1_Div2/file3.txt
Round1Div2/file4.txt renamed as Round_1_Div2/file4.txt
Round2Div2/file3.txt renamed as Round_2_Div2/file3.txt
Round2Div2/file4.txt renamed as Round_2_Div2/file4.txt
```

Comment: Thank you, It's working but the problem is, I have directories like ```Round783Div.2```. There is more one digit number in the middle also it ther is a ```.``` after ```Div```. I am not familiar with perl-rename wild cards .

Comment: could you help me?? can I use regular wild card with perl-rename??

Comment: try `s/Round(\d+)Div\.(\d+)/Round_$1_Div$2/`.   that will work with the `.` before Div and with any number of digits.   BTW, they're regular expressions, not "wild cards".  If you're not familiar with them, you should strive to become so as quickly as possible - REs are used **everywhere** with unix command-line tools.

Comment: There are several variants of regular expressions.  The ones you most need to know are Basic REs (BRE), Extended REs (ERE), and perl or perl-compatible REs (PCRE).    They're all very similar, but with different features & capabilities, and slightly different syntax (e.g.   `+` has to be escaped in BRE to have the special meaning of "one or more of", while it has to be escaped in ERE or PCRE to **not** have that meaning, to be treated as a literal plus character).

Comment: both `sed` and `grep` use BRE by default (but can use ERE with the -E option.  GNU grep can also do PCRE with the -P option).   awk uses ERE.  perl uses perl REs, of course....and PCRE itself is a subset of perl's own RE (mostly because some of perlre only really makes sense to use inside a perl program...so it's the subset that's useful outside of perl).   perl/pcre is the most capable and full-featured variant.

Comment: Thank you so much, I am just a newbie with less than a year of experience. I didn't know RE is a thing in Linux/Unix although I used sed, grep,ripgrep, etc. before. Thank you for guiding me. I will definitely learn RE

Comment: BTW ```perl-rename``` is the command in *Arch Linux* instead of ```rename```.It confused me a little(package is also named ```perl-rename```. Anyway it worked :)

Comment: @MohamedIrfan thanks, i'll have to remember that.  I've written a lot of answers using perl rename and I like to add all the various names that it's known by.   It's kind of annoying that it isn't just `rename` everywhere because the alternatives are pretty nearly useless in comparison.

Answer (score 0):

It seems easiest to use something like

```bsh
mv -i Round1Div2/* Round_1_Div2 && rmdir Round1Div2
mv -i Round2Div2/* Round_2_Div2 && rmdir Round2Div2
```

If there are name collisions, the `-i` option to `mv` should give you an interactive prompt asking you whether you want to overwrite the file.

If you have hidden filenames, or *many thousands* of files, then you may want to use `rsync`:

```bsh
rsync -av --ignore-existing Round1Div2/ Round_1_Div2
rsync -av --ignore-existing Round2Div2/ Round_2_Div2
```

Note that the `/` at the end of the source directory name is intentional.  This would recreate the file hierarchy of the source directories under the target directories, and would not overwrite existing data.  The source directories would be left in place (so this *copies* rather than moves, unless you also add the option `--remove-source-files`).

Answer (score 0):

I would use `mv -S dup folder1/* folder2`

You can use `mv` interactively with `-i` as [other answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/647706/469418) suggests. Or you can use `-S` [--suffix=SUFFIX](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/mv.1.html). That means if a file.txt is already present, then that file in new location would be renamed as file.txtdup( with -S dup).

#### Using `awk` :

Because you have directories listed in textfiles.The following awk command may be used for this purpose:

`awk '{ printf "mv -S dup %s/* ", $0 ; getline < "newname.txt"; printf "%s\n", $0 }' rename.txt`